# Generate primes p and q such that p | q-1

Tags: openssl, primes

Is there a command line usage of openssl that generates primes p and q such that p divides q-1?

Thanks all!

Comment: Easy.  q = any odd prime; p = 2.  If there are more restrictions on the values of the two primes, then you need to tell us.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to tell that the primes should have a specific bit size